# Is there a possible way to return a for loop result into function like ternary operator?

Tags: c++

We've seen so far that how a ternary operator works:

```
return (x == y) ? x : y; ' If x equals to y, then return x, otherwise y
```

The alternative code could be written as follows:

```
if (x == y)
    return x;
else
    return y;
```

The question is, is this possible to return the sum of N numbers using a return statement with For loop?

An illustrative example for this question:

```
#include <iostream>

int forLoop(int);

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Sum of 1 + 2 + 3: " << forLoop(3);

    return 0;
}

int forLoop(int x) {
    int sum = 0;

    return (for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) sum += i);
    // Expecting to return (1 + 2 + 3 = 6) to the function using loop and return.
}
```

And I get the following errors:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int forLoop(int)’:
main.cpp:14:13: error: expected primary-expression before ‘for’
     return (for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) sum += i);
             ^~~
main.cpp:14:13: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘for’
main.cpp:14:29: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
     return (for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) sum += i);
                             ^
```

Is there any possible way to do it in a single line rather than:

```
int forLoop(int x) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
        sum += i;
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: via macros or helper functions, but I can't think of anything standard. To be honest I don't know if I like that `(for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) sum += i);` would somehow return `sum`.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you (think that you) want or need to do that?  There might be a better way to accomplish your actual goal.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, the reason is, I just wanted to know if there's easier way to write the same expression.

Comment: The standard way to do something like this would (IMO) be [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use recursion. The tail recursion will be optimized for stack usage.

```
int forLoop(int x) {
  return x < 1 ? 0 : (x + forLoop(x - 1));
}
```

Comment: Perfect. This is the best method.

Comment: To nitpick however, it's not tail recursion. Though it's pretty close for a compiler to optimize anyway, I reckon.

Comment: To double-nitpick, C++ optimizers may-or-may-not support tail recursion (it's not required by the standard), and for most tail-recursion to work there shouldn't be outstanding operations after the recursion call (because those interfere with the tail-recursion optimization, since they usually require retaining the stack frame so the operation can be carried out when the tail call returns).

Answer (score 5):

You could use the closed form of the sum of natural numbers:

```
int forLoop(int n)
{
  return n * (n + 1) / 2;
}
```

This has no `for` loops.

With `range-v3` you could do:

```
int forLoop(int n)
{
  return ranges::accumulate(ranges::views::iota(1, n + 1), 0);
}
```

No `for` loops here either.

For completeness, the standard approach to avoid loops would involve the use of algorithms, as pointed out in the comments. This could look like:

```
int forLoop(int n)
{
  std::vector<int> v;
  std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);
  return std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);
}
```

I'm not recommending this last option, of course, since it needlessly allocates `O(n)` space and takes `O(n)` time for an `O(1)` space/time algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, via lambdas (unless you consider that cheating):

```
int forLoop(int x) {
    return [&](){
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) sum += i);
        return sum;
    }();
}
```

EDIT: if you're okay with non-standard (but widely supported) extensions, gcc has statement expressions, supported in most systems, already circulated on the standardization committee's list:

```
int forLoop(int x) {
    int sum = 0;

    return ({
        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) sum += i);
        sum;
    });
}
```

Comment: For my money, that's cheating :p "I just wanted to know if there's easier way to write the same expression."

Comment: There's a sort-of-ongoing (or rather stalled) standardization of 'statement expressions'. gcc can do that, updating the answer.

Comment: Ah go on then, you can have that.

Comment: Edited the answer.

GNU's doc:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html

a working version of the pre-proposal circulated a long time ago, in case you want to continue:
http://lorro.hu/cplusplus/statement_expressions.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that's also well working and explained method.